# Liferay api to find out if system configured to ldap or to liferay database

Tags: ldap, liferay, liferay-6, spring-ldap

I would like to know if there is an api to find out if the Liferay system is configured for ldap or not.  Is there any api exposed by liferay which can give me this information ?

Any help is appreciated

thanks
Lokesh

Comment: There is no API for this, but the values are stored in `PortalPreferences` and you can also get it from your `portal-ext.properties` if the [configuration is done through overriding liferay's `portal.properties`](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/ldap) by fetching the value for keys: 1) `ldap.auth.enabled=false`
2) `ldap.auth.required=false`

Answer (score 0):

This is a double ended blade.

1 . If the portal is setup with ldap via configurations in portal-ext.properties then use

```
Boolean ldapAuthEnabled = Boolean.valueOf(PropsUtil.get("ldap.auth.enabled"));
```

The above line returns true if ldap auth property is set to true in the ext props file.

2 . If the portal ldap properties are set in the GUI (Control Panel) then you have to retrieve it via Portal/Portlet Props. This can be done via any of the following:

```
com.liferay.portal.model.PortalPreferences portalPrefs = com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.PortalPreferencesUtil.fetchByO_O(ownerId, ownerType);
com.liferay.portal.model.PortalPreferences portalPrefs = com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.PortalPreferencesUtil.fetchByO_O(ownerId, ownerType, retrieveFromCache);
com.liferay.portal.model.PortalPreferences portalPrefs = com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.PortalPreferencesUtil.fetchByPrimaryKey(portalPreferencesId);
```

But liferay advices against using the PortalPreferencesUtil:

> The persistence utility for the portal preferences service. This
>   utility wraps PortalPreferencesPersistenceImpl and provides direct
>   access to the database for CRUD operations. This utility should only
>   be used by the service layer, as it must operate within a transaction.
>   Never access this utility in a JSP, controller, model, or other
>   front-end class.

For a clearer idea, try running this query and inspecting the XML result in the PREFERENCES column:

```
select * from PORTALPREFERENCES where lower(preferences) like '%ldap%';
```

You will have to use both of these solutions with an OR condition to get a definite solution.